# Refreshing Data Connections in Excel 2010 VBA

Tags: vba, excel

So I have all of my VBA code down and it seems to be right, but it just is not refreshing the workbooks. The only thing that I can think of is when I open up the sheets I have to enable editting, so would I need to add something to my code?

Edit: I am running this through a VBScript

```
Public wb As Workbook

Sub executeUpdate()
    `some code
     openBook path & testArray(i) & ext, True
     saveBookAs path & testArray(i)
End Sub

Sub openBook(ByVal fileName As String, ByVal refresh As Boolean)

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fileName, 0, False)

    If refresh = True Then
        wb.RefreshAll
    End If
End Sub

Sub saveBookAs(ByVal fName As String)
    wb.SaveAs fileName:=fName & "_posReport.xlsx"
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried opening the workbook manually, enable editing, then running the `RefreshAll` code to check if it is working at all?

Comment: Well what I did was opened the workbook, before enabling editing I started recording a macro and went through all of the steps to refresh the table. Looked at the code and all it said was `ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll`

Comment: Ok, I get how you recorded the code. But to check if the `RefreshAll` is working at all, I suggest you open the workbook manually, enable editing and then run the `RefreshAll`.

Comment: @JazzyJoop so I did that and was messing around with it, I had to turn off background refreshing before hitting refresh. And it worked, however, last night when the VBScript ran there was an error somewhere... so now I'm just trying to figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

I found this code over [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9df35ebe-1724-444a-bc94-f170bd0737b6/excel-2010-enable-editing?forum=isvvba):

```
If Application.ProtectedViewWindows.Count > 0 Then
    Application.ActiveProtectedViewWindow.Edit
End If
```

Have not tested it, but maybe it works for you.

--
*Quote:*

> *code will bypass the need for the user to select the "Enable Editing" button on the message bar below the ribbon. One additional note [...] the code will error if the workbook isn't in "ProtectedView". So to avoid this the following code will only enable editing if the workbook has "ProtectedView" enabled.*

Comment: oooh, looks promising. Do you know whether or not I will need to do that every time I open a new workbook? because I have a loop that goes through the code to open and refresh workbooks one by one.

Comment: I guess you would have to enable editing for each workbook. Then the line would be added to your *openBook* procedure.

Comment: No dice... it saves the workbook the way I want it to, but when I open it up and I manually hit refresh new data (from yesterday) comes in...